# How can I store the same value in multiple keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary something like this:

```
odd_even = {1: 'odd', 2: 'even', 3: 'odd', 4: 'even', 5: 'odd', 6: 'even', 7: 'odd', 8: 'even', 9: 'odd'}
```

Here, all the odd number values are the same. I think assigning something like this is redundant.

I tried this way.

```
odd_even = {}
odd_even[1, 3, 5, 7, 9] = 'odd'
odd_even[2, 4, 6, 8] = 'even'
```

But I can't access the value using the key because they are stored as a tuple:

```
print(odd_even[1])
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Probably not going to work the way you want; keys can't be mutuable.  "Values that are not hashable, that is, values containing lists, dictionaries or other mutable types (that are compared by value rather than by object identity) may not be used as keys."  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Comment: Is there a reason why you want a dict rather than a simple function that returns either `'odd'` or `'even'` based on the input argument?

Comment: @blhsing I used it just for example purposes.

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the calculation, it may be more efficient, both time and memory-wise, to keep it a simple function instead of a dict, as is the case here.

Comment: Just use a loop

Comment: Why have a dictionary?  It is a 1-liner for a function...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a quick way to do this.  Your best bet is probably a for-loop:

```py
odd_even = {}
for num in range(10):
    odd_even[num] = 'odd' if num&1 else 'even'
print(odd_even)
```

```
Out: {0: 'even', 1: 'odd', 2: 'even', 3: 'odd', 4: 'even', 5: 'odd', 6: 'even', 7: 'odd', 8: 'even', 9: 'odd'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary comprehension:

```py
odd = {k: 'odd' for k in range(1, 10, 2)}
even = {k: 'even' for k in range(2, 10, 2)}
odd_even = {**odd, **even}  # or even.update(odd)
```

You can do both with one line:

```py
odd_even = {k: 'odd' if k % 2 == 0 else 'even' for k in range(1, 10)}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to skin this cat :) Say, a dictionary comprehension that looks up the right definition using the remainder (modulo) operator:

```
{i: ["even", "odd"][i % 2] for i in range(1, 10)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary comprehension:

```
odd_even = { key: 'odd' if key % 2 else 'even' for key in range(1, 11) }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not that grammer in python. Maybe loop is the best solution.

```
odd_even = dict()
for i in (1, 3, 5, 7, 9):
    odd_even[i] = "odd"
for i in (2, 4, 6, 8):
    odd_even[i] = "even"
odd_even = dict(sorted(odd_even.items()))
print(odd_even)
```

Or you can use this grammer:

```
odd_even = dict(sorted({**{x: "odd" for x in (1, 3, 5, 7, 9)}, **{x: "even" for x in (2, 4, 6, 8)}}.items()))
print(odd_even)
```